# ¿Por qué imprime esto: [I@1db9742?

Tags: java, array

Soy nuevo en java y no estoy entendiendo bien que pasa con mi código:

```
public class miraarar {

     static int[] sacarElementos(int[]a){
         int[]b = new int[a.length-2];
         for(int i=1;i<a.length-1;i++){
             b[i-1]=a[i];
         }
         return b;
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[]arr={1,2,3,4};
        System.out.println(sacarElementos(arr));
    }
}
```

Se supone que mi código me tiene que sacar el primer y el ultimo elemento de mi arreglo pero me imprime esto por consola `[I@1db9742` que no sé que significa. Se supone que debe imprimir los números 2 y 3, pero no lo hace. Si alguien podría ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: Lo que pasa, es que el método `println` invoca al método [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) de la clase `Object` y devolverá una representación textual del objeto: `nameClass + '@' + Hashcode`.. En tu caso, `[I` es el nombre de la clase y `1db9742` es el código hash del objeto.

Answer (score 2):

Estás imprimendo la referencia de la memoria, necesitas:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

y después

```
Arrays.toString(arr)
```

Comment: porque al intentar  importar java.util.Arrays; me dice "the import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved"

Comment: @EzequielYT pues esa clase está desde hace rato [(documentación)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). Puedes editar tu pregunta y **añadir** cómo intentaste usar esta respuesta junto con el mensaje de error completo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

En el **método main** después de llenar los datos de **arr** haz esto:

```
int[] auxArr = sacarElementos(arr);

for (int i = 0; i < auxArr.length - 1; i++)
{
     System.out.println(auxArr[i]);
}
```

De la forma en que lo estás haciendo no estás imprimiendo los elementos del arreglo sino la dirección que ocupa este en memoria.

Para hacerlo correctamente debes recorrer todos sus elementos con un **ciclo for** e irlos imprimiendo uno a uno como en el ejemplo de arriba.